# Changing colour of legend text same as mentioned colour of geom_point() using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have legend having three values namely - high low med.

[image]

I want the colour of text **high** to same as shape object i.e blue and low as red and
med as green
Colour are mentioned in geom_point().

Is it possible to change the colour of legend text?

Answer (score 1):

If `p` is your plot, you can save it as a grob and edit the labels one-by-one with grid commands,

```
g = ggplotGrob(p)
grid.draw(g)
grid.edit("label-3", grep=TRUE, global=TRUE,
           gp=gpar(col="red", cex=1))
```